Circuit Diagram for powering 32 motors
I am working on a project in which I have to power 32 different motors with different rated currents and powers. The smallest motor has a rated power of 36W and a current of 1A, whereas the largest one has a rated power of 750W and a current of 9A.
My question is: how do I go about designing the schematic? I was planning to connect to either a combination of or a single 48V battery. The motors all operate on a supply voltage from 24-48V.
I am only curious how to ensure the rated current goes through the motors. The motors themselves have a low resistance, the 36W one with a resistance of 2.08 Ohms. Using \$V=I*R\$, I get that to limit the current to 1A, I would need a resistor with a resistance of about 41.76 Ohms, however, it would also need to be rated at about 41.76W since \$P = I^2*R\$. With no resistor, I calculate the current to be about 23.08A, which would probably blow it up, lol.
Am I going about this the right way? I feel stumped and need some guidance on how to approach this. My practical experience with DC motors is nonexistent so please feel free to fill in the gaps from my assumptions.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You cannot use a resistor to (reliably) limit current through a motor. Motor current will vary depending on the mechanical load you put on it. You need to provide the correct supply Voltage to reach motor, and make sure that your power supplies are capable of providing the motors' max rated current.

Fortunately the motor determines the current as a function of the torque being delivered.  You have to worry about the drivers.

This is normal to have a start current in DC motors that is >=10x rated current and 12x in highly efficient DC motors. If you compute more than this I'd be suspicious.
The answer is to use current-regulated Motor Controllers for each with adequate voltage input range and excess load-rated power, cooling and adequate voltage output range in the controller.
The choice of voltage power sources and motor controllers are based on these parameters along with the power margin for any excess load to speed up or slow down from high inertia if any.
The current in motor controllers is PWM modulated with clamp and snubber circuits and sensing with RPM and/or current sensing to limit overpowering a motor-controller device with constant max. acceleration, (and max torque with current limit).  This best done with RPM feedback but adequate control is with current limits and variable voltage but expected worse speed load regulation with lower voltage and current limit not > 10x rated current. So RPM feedback is best and cheap if integrated into the controller. But this adds some complexity and cost with low power circuits that tend to be much less than 10x higher power power sources and the bonus with servo regulated speed control which also prevents over-heating of the power source with adequate margin to max temperature rise.
There are plenty of tradeoffs with cost, quality, choice of power voltage, and DCDC down converters for lower power/voltage motors but these are my guidelines for making these choices.
The biggest power supply with the highest voltage for just the big motor(s) and another for all the smaller motors might be possible with 24 to 48 electronic MC's.
If you are cascading DCDC converters one must consider load-regulated noise mitigation methods of filtering to prevent crosstalk and resonance.
Choosing the motor control units depends on your dynamic load and speed control requirements.  A 30% power margin is a good rule-of-thumb to increase life expectancy from junction temperature in the controller and motor windings as a temp. rise in all parts that can fail from heat will "thank you". A  less than 50% power load is better with redundancy and balanced-current sharing will reduce down-time when something goes wrong.
This is not a DIY project for a new project in motor controller applications so an experienced Engineer's advice on each application is recommended in your many choices with dynamic load profile specs.
Naturally getting them all in the same voltage range is good but you don't want your big motor controller to bring down the voltage on the rest.
